# How to create a static JSON files with Element API and cache it with Varnish

Tags: cache, plugin-elementapi, varnish

Is it possible to create static JSON file using the Element API plugin?

What I then want to do was cache that file probably using Varnish or push it to an S3 bucket.

If I was to cache it I would need to look at purging the URL when an entry is added or edited.
If I pushed it to S3, then I would either need to overwrite the file or manage it another way.

What would be the best way to handle this, and could you easily create a static JSON file with caching and purging abilities?

Comment: Would it be an option to cache it locally? The Craft HTMLCache plugin (https://github.com/craftapi/htmlcache) is currently in beta, but busts the cache when an entry is edited and automatically expires after an hour..

Comment: Was HTMLCache useful in this case or did you go with another method? I'm in a similar situation now so just curious as to what worked for other people.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure how you can do this, but you could manually print the response to a file yourself on a regular basis (as a cron job) using wget:

This:

```
wget -S http://craft.fira/fullmembers.json
```

…saves the JSON into a file named fullmembers.json into the directory it was run from.

Here is the solution that I have used in a cron job that runs every minute:

```
wget -O - http://www.fira.co.uk/fullmembers.json > /home/forge/www.fira.co.uk/public/jsoncache/fullmembers-temp.json
rm /home/forge/www.fira.co.uk/public/jsoncache/fullmembers.json
mv /home/forge/www.fira.co.uk/public/jsoncache/fullmembers-temp.json /home/forge/www.fira.co.uk/public/jsoncache/fullmembers.json
```

Comment: Interesting. Have you noticed a big improvement in the speed of data access from the app(s) consuming the API? At the moment this is a bottleneck for me. I'm not sure if it's the server response time or the DB queries

Comment: For what I have been using it for the response time has been very quick. I have made sure to keep the limit fairly low and rinse pagination, otherwise that does slow it down, plus I have been using eager loading where I can.