# Serializing assets field is returning a serialized criteria object, but how to return serialized data?

Tags: json, content, serialization

I'm saving a custom element that has content by field layout.
When successfully saved, I return the object in the response.
Now, most of the data is usable but the assets field is just a serialized criteria query.

```
return $this->asJson([
    'success' => true,
    'quotation' => $quotation
]);
```

Comment: This might help, seems you'll need to use ElementAPI (if you don't already) though.
https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/a/15867/10058
[Element API](https://github.com/craftcms/element-api#installation) - as mentioned by these [Craft 3 docs](https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/dev/headless.html#json-api)